# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension on mac. unable to install racc

Tags: ios, ruby, macos, automation

Installing racc 1.5.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/racc-1.5.2/ext/racc/cparse
```

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby -I

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r

./siteconf20210323-1013-1j708gz.rb extconf.rb

checking for rb_ary_subseq()... *** extconf.rb failed ***

Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary

libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
--with-opt-dir
--without-opt-dir
--with-opt-include
--without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
--with-opt-lib
--without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
--with-make-prog
--without-make-prog
--srcdir=.
--curdir

--ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in
`try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)

You have to install development tools first.

from/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:546:in `block in try_link0'

from/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tmpdir.rb:93:in`mktmpdir'

from/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:543:in`try_link0'

from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in`try_link'

from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:782:in`try_func'

from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1069:in`block in have_func'

from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in`block in checking_for'

from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in`block (2 levels) in postpone'

from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in`open'

from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in`block in postpone'

from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in`open'

from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in`postpone'

from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in`checking_for'

from
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1068:in`have_func'

from extconf.rb:6:in `'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/racc-1.5.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/racc-1.5.2 for
inspection.

Results logged to
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/extensions/universal-darwin-19/2.6.0/racc-1.5.2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing racc (1.5.2), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install racc -v '1.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
rails was resolved to 6.1.3, which depends on
actioncable was resolved to 6.1.3, which depends on
actionpack was resolved to 6.1.3, which depends on
actionview was resolved to 6.1.3, which depends on
rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
nokogiri was resolved to 1.11.2, which depends on
racc

Comment: another gem that have the same dependency who needs another version? check this and manually install the explicit version you need of a gem "gem install gem_name -v x.x.x...

Answer (score 3):

The gem racc has the following dependencies:

```
 *  Ruby 1.8.x or later.
(*) make and C compiler.
```

See: [Gem documentation](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/racc/1.4.14#label-Requirement)

So my guess is that either one of those are not correctly installed on your machine.

1. Does `ruby -v` work?
2. Does `make -v` work?
3. Does `gcc -v` work?

To install ruby, you might want to look into rbenv (https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)
To install make and gcc, simply run:

```
xcode-select --install
```